# Eval a string representation of tuples in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a column of string values which looks like this:

```
d = {'col1': '(100,200),(150,124),(135,137)'}
```

And I need to change this to float values to become this:

```
d = {'col1': [(100,200),(150,124),(135,137)]}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try using `ast.literal_eval`. You can wrap your strings in braces and safe-eval them:

```
import ast
d = {k : ast.literal_eval(f'[{v}]') for k, v in d.items()}
```

```
pd.DataFrame(d)

         col1
0  (100, 200)
1  (150, 124)
2  (135, 137)
```

Comment: `df.assign(coordinates=[literal_eval(f'[{v}]') for v in df.coordinates])`

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, add sqare brackets around the string:
`{'col1': '[(100, 200), (150, 124), (135, 137)]'}`

Later on, `eval ()` that string.

```
d['col1'] = '[' + d['col1'] + ']'
d['col1'] = eval(d['col1'])

print(d)
# {'col1': [(100, 200), (150, 124), (135, 137)]}

pd.DataFrame(d)
```